# Eigenvalues for a $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix

Tags: eigenvalues

In *Mathematica*, I computed the following:

```
Eigenvalues[{{1/3, ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2],1/6}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b ) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/ 6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2]}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b ) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6,1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2]}, {1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b ) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 1/3 }}]
```

and obtained the answer as

```
{1/6, 1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 
 192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1],1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}
```

Please let me know how to read the last three eigenvalues.

Comment: See documentation for `Root`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ev = Eigenvalues[{{1/
     3, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 
    1/6}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 
    1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/
     6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2]}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6, 
    1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2]}, {1/
     6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 1/3}}]

(* {1/6, 1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 
     192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 
     192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 1/6 Root[-3 + 44 a^2 + 64 a^3 + 44 b^2 - 
     192 a b^2 + (7 - 36 a^2 - 36 b^2) #1 - 5 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]} *)
```

[`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) will convert the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects to (the much more complicated) radical expressions

```
ev // ToRadicals // Simplify

(* {1/6, (1/72)*(20 + 
        (8*(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2))/
          (1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3) + 
        8*(1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3)), 
   (1/144)*(40 - (8*I*(-I + Sqrt[3])*
             (1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2))/
          (1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3) + 
        8*I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
          (1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3)), 
   (1/144)*(40 + (8*I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
             (1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2))/
          (1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3) - 
        8*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*
          (1 + 27*a^2 - 108*a^3 + 
               27*b^2 + 324*a*b^2 + 
               Sqrt[-(1 + 27*a^2 + 27*b^2)^
                       3 + (1 + 27*a^2 - 
                        108*a^3 + 27*b^2 + 
                        324*a*b^2)^2])^(1/3))} *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use the option [`Cubics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cubics.html) in [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html)

```
ev = Eigenvalues[{{1/
     3, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 
    1/6}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 
    1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/
     6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2]}, {((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6, 
    1/6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2]}, {1/
     6, ((a + Sqrt[3] b) - I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[
      2], ((a + Sqrt[3] b) + I (Sqrt[3] a - b))/6 Sqrt[2], 1/3}}, 
  Cubics -> True]//Simplify
```